# How can I take look at the inside of the atmega1280?

Tags: atmega, debugging

I want take a look at the memory and at the elements inside the atmega1280.
I compiled Ardupilot sketch and I uploaded it with an arduino.

I started avarice with the following command:

```
$ avarice --mkII --capture --jtag usb :4242
```

and I started avr-gdb

```
$ avr-gdb /tmp/build5831285936308447966.tmp/ArduPilotMega.cpp.elf
```

I typed:

```
(gdb)target remote localhost:4242
```

and this is the answer:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:4242
Remote debugging using localhost:4242
0xfffffffe in ?? ()
```

when I do `list` it show me

```
#include <WProgram.h>

int main(void)
{
    init();

    setup();

    for (;;)
        loop();

    return 0;
}
```

That is not my ardupilot!

I don't understand why I get the ?? symbol after the target command and why I get a different source after the list command.

Could someone explain where is my error, how they work and the reason of those symbols?
More important, how can I take a look inside of the atmega1280?

P.S.: I compiled with Arduino, so I compiled with the -g flag.

Edit:
I used an unofficial jtagice mkii:

[image]

and I follow this guide for the setting http://www.diydronesafety.com/topic/72-articleundocumented-apm2x-jtag-technique-and-jtag-for-apm1x-using-only-the-redboard/

So mine is presented like this:

[image]

Comment: ... in fact that *is* what every arduino sketch looks like you simply implement setup and loop in a separate file than that one...

Comment: As viactcu suggests, everything looks fine.  Try tracing into the setup() or loop() calls and see if it's as you expect. up.  If not, you may have told the development-machine-side gdb to reference the wrong elf object.

Answer (score -1):

You should think about investing in JTAGICE MKII, it supports many Atmel device. When you use it with Atmel AVR Studio, debugging is a breeze and it allows you to look inside all the devices.

Comment: So, are you saying that i can't do it without atmel avr studio?

Comment: AVR Studio is free and is easily the best debugging interface for Atmel chips. I would peruse through AVRfreaks.net too if you're looking for more help with this; I bet the forums there have what you're looking for. As a side note I have the JTAGICE3 and it was probably the best money I ever spent on a debugger.